# Django admin: including some data from the database in a change_form

Tags: javascript, django, django-admin

I'm using Django 1.2.4. I have an admin class for a model that has JavaScript media. I would like to make some data from the database available to these scripts. I'm not sure what the best way to do this would be.

Perhaps something like this: (not that I think this is valid, just trying to get my point across.)

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
         js = ("js/baz.js")
         raw_js = "var boo = %s; var bar = %s" % (boo, bar)
```

I considered making a template at `/templates/admin/foo-app/foo/change_form.html`, but I'm not sure how I would put the `boo` and `bar` values into the template. (They are calculated from the database.)

What is the correct approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `ModelAdmin.change_view` to pass in whatever variables you wish to the `change_form` template.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view

You could also potentially (untested) define a view in your `ModelAdmin`, map it to a URL with `ModelAdmin.get_urls`, and pass in that url to the admin media.

That way you wouldn't have to override a template.